# jQuery: Multiple selector issue

Tags: jquery

I am having problems showing divs where the div has three selectors I need to match on. These are typical:

```
<div class="pinfo draft sept-2010">...</div>
<div class="pinfo published feb-2011">...</div>
etc...
```

There is always `pinfo` followed by review state (published or draft) and then time frame (month + year)

This is what I currently have:

```
// Hide all rows
$(".pinfo").hide();
// Now, show those rows where the selectors are in the filters built
for (idx in $cls)
{
    console.log('filter: '+$cls[idx]);
    $('.pinfo').filter($cls[idx]).show();
}
```

where $cls is an array of strings. The strings are class selectors built given then choices made by the user from an input form. For example:

```
$cls = [".Draft .sept-2011", 
        ".Published .sept-2011"]
```

I am having problems showing divs where the div has three selectors I need to match on.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!
Eric

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: I am having problems showing divs where the div has three selectors I need to match on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use a `for..in` loop on an an array. Only use them on objects, and only with `hasOwnProperty`.  You can use jQuery's [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each) here to loop through the array.
2. The big problem.  A selector like `".Draft .sept-2011"` says "find elements with the class `sept-2011` that have an ancestor element with the class `Draft`.  You can combine multiple class selectors: what you want is `.Draft.sept-2011`.

So your code might look like this:

```
$cls = [".Draft.sept-2011", 
        ".Published.sept-2011"]

var $pinfo = $('.pinfo').hide();
$.each($cls, function(idx, val) {
    $pinfo.filter(val).show();
});
```

Note that I've also cached the `$('.pinfo')` selector call for the sake of performance.

Comment: Thank you for this. And, with $.each() I was able to simplify other code on my page!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$('.pinfo').parent().find($cls[idx]).show();
```